# load xml infile mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am trying to load xml file into mysql.
My XML looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEST>
    <DATABASE>
        <CUSTOMERS>
            <CUSTOMER l_name="aa" f_name="aaaa">
                <adr>
                    <street txt="mainstreet" zipcode="11111"/>
                </adr>
                <adr>
                    <street txt="secondstreet" zipcode="11111"/>
                </adr>                
            </CUSTOMER>
            <CUSTOMER l_name="bb" f_name="bbbb">
                <adr>
                    <street txt="teststreet" zipcode="22222"/>
                </adr>
            </CUSTOMER>            
            <CUSTOMER l_name="cc" f_name="cccc"/>
        </CUSTOMERS>
    </DATABASE>
</TEST>
```

My code to import the file in the mysql is:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/uebung/customer.xml'
INTO TABLE customer
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<CUSTOMER>';
```

So it works. But if I have two addresses for a customer then it tooks only the last one in the database. That is, it just loads for the customer with the `l_name = aa` the address with the second street. The address with mainstream isn't loaded in the DB.

How I have to change my MYSQL Code?

Answer (score 0):

Using CUSTOMER as the record node: `ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<CUSTOMER>'`,
each property tag inside of every `<CUSTOMER>` tag must be unique, so if you declare the same node twice (in this case, `<adr>`), the second node's value overwrites the first node's value.  So you've basically nested too many times.

Try this instead:

```
<TEST>
    <DATABASE>
        <CUSTOMERS>
            <CUSTOMER l_name="aa" f_name="aaaa">
                <adr>
                    <street txt="mainstreet" zipcode="11111"/>
                </adr>
            </CUSTOMER>
            <CUSTOMER l_name="aa" f_name="aaaa">
                <adr>
                    <street txt="secondstreet" zipcode="11111"/>
                </adr>                
            </CUSTOMER>
            <CUSTOMER l_name="bb" f_name="bbbb">
                <adr>
                    <street txt="teststreet" zipcode="22222"/>
                </adr>
            </CUSTOMER>            
            <CUSTOMER l_name="cc" f_name="cccc"/>
        </CUSTOMERS>
    </DATABASE>
</TEST>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The Problem is that I get the XML in this format like I wrote in my Question. Is there no other chance to solve it. I tried it before with PHP but it is very complicated because this xml is only a simple example. In reality the xml file could be more nested. That is if it is possible I want to do it in mysql directly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider running [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) in PHP to transform your original XML into the MySQL 
format you need.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- IdentityTransform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CUSTOMER[*[name(*)!='addr']]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="adr">
        <xsl:element name="CUSTOMER">
          <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::CUSTOMER/@l_name"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::CUSTOMER/@f_name"/>
          <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:copy-of select="*"/> 
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP** *(using [php-xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class)*

```
// Set current path
$cd = dirname(__FILE__);

// Load the XML source and XSLT file    
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');   
$xml->load($cd.'/Source.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load($cd.'/XSLTScript.xsl');

// Transform the original xml
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// Save output to file
$xmlfile = $cd.'/Output.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $newXml);
```

**Output** *(use Output.xml in MySQL's `LOAD DATA XML` command)*

```
<TEST>
  <DATABASE>
    <CUSTOMERS>
      <CUSTOMER l_name="aa" f_name="aaaa">
        <adr>
          <street txt="mainstreet" zipcode="11111"/>
        </adr>
      </CUSTOMER>
      <CUSTOMER l_name="aa" f_name="aaaa">
        <adr>
          <street txt="secondstreet" zipcode="11111"/>
        </adr>
      </CUSTOMER>
      <CUSTOMER l_name="bb" f_name="bbbb">
        <adr>
          <street txt="teststreet" zipcode="22222"/>
        </adr>
      </CUSTOMER>
      <CUSTOMER l_name="cc" f_name="cccc"/>
    </CUSTOMERS>
  </DATABASE>
</TEST>
```